# Generic Anchor link click even capture and retireve id and call method

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a few anchor links as part of my views.  Upon click of the image within the anchor link RegisterToolTip is called which calls the server to recieve the tool tip.  I have noticed that the first time I click the link it would hit the server and second time when I click it it would not hit the server.

I register the two links as follows in my document.ready function. I want to hit the server everytime the link is click to get the most accurate information. The first time it hits the server and then it adds the tool tip but would not refresh again

```
RegisterToolTip(toolTipUrl, 'qTipTags', 'qTipTags');
RegisterToolTip(toolTipUrl, 'qTipImportFiles', 'qTipImportFiles');
```

HTML:

```
<a id="qTipTags" href='' ">
    <img src="../../Content/images/icon_tooltip.gif" alt="B" />
</a>
```

JS:

```
function RegisterToolTip(action, ctrlId, dispInfoId) {
    $("#" + ctrlId).attr("rel", action).cluetip({
        closePosition: "top",
        activation: 'click',
        width: 350,
        sticky: true,
        debug: true,
        showTitle: true,
        dropShadow: true,
        cache: false,
        cluetipClass: 'default',
        closeText: '<div class="ui-state-error-icon ui-icon-closethick" id="close" title="Close"/>',
        mouseOutClose: true,
        ajaxSettings: {
            type: "post",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                "id": dispInfoId
            }
        },
        ajaxProcess: function (dataOut) {
            $("#" + ctrlId).data("title", dataOut["Field"]);
            return dataOut["Description"];
        },
        onShow: function (ct, c) {
            var t = $("#" + ctrlId).data("title");
            $("#cluetip-title").text(t);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With a generic handler like this:

```
function clickHandlerForAnchors(e){
   var id = $(this).attr("id");  //This gets the id of the clicked anchor
   ...
   RegisterToolTip(action, id, dispInfoId);   
}
```

Then you bind it with something like:

```
$("a").click(clickHandlerForAnchors);  //The selector is up to you here
```

(I know the handler doesn't have to be created as a separate function, but I did it just in case you need to reuse it).

Cheers

Comment: I tried that and it goes to Server Error in '/' Application page. I did not define any onlick in the anchor tag itself, just used the above generic handles and binded it in function On Ready()

Comment: please add an `alert(id)` to see if the problem is not in the code I gave you.

Comment: The id is correct, I revised the question, could you please take a look at the question. Basically I get tool tip from the serverwhen the link is clicked. it only hits the server teh first time and then adds the tool tip. clikcing the link the second time will show the tool tip but will not hit the server. i am trying to make it hit the server everytime so i get the most upto date data

Comment: Are you using the code I posted to attach the click listener?